# extract 2D array data from an XML file using python

Tags: python, arrays, xml

I have a depth map of a stereo image witch is saved as an xml file, I want to extract the 2D float array from this file and save it as a float image, I solved the second part of my request witch is saving the 2D array as a float image successfully, I have searched relevant answers but I don't find, so would anyone help me please? my XML files look similar to this:

```
?xml version="1.0"?

opencv_storage

depth type_id="opencv-matrix"

   rows 480 /rows

   cols 640 /cols

   dt f /dt

   data

    2.66372559e+02 2.66372559e+02 2.66372559e+02 2.66372559e+02
    2.66372559e+02 2.66372559e+02 2.66372559e+02 2.66372559e+02
    2.66372559e+02 2.66372559e+02 2.66372559e+02 2.66372559e+02
    2.66372559e+02 2.66372559e+02 2.66372559e+02 2.65196075e+02
    2.64019592e+02 2.64019592e+02 2.64019592e+02 2.64019592e+02
    2.64019592e+02 2.63823517e+02 2.63823517e+02 2.64607849e+02 ....
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: @GrayCygnus Thank you for replay and for advice, certainly I will have a look to these links.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem as follow:

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2

cv_file = cv2.FileStorage("test.xml", cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)       % reading my xml file as a storage file
             matrix = cv_file.getNode("depth").mat()               % getting the node of the 2D array named "depth" as shown in the  above xml file.
             img1 = Image.fromarray(matrix)                        % reading the 2D array as an image
             img1.save(dest, "tiff")                               % saving the image with a tiff format
```